# Simulating electromagnetic propagation from a vector plane

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, simulations, photonics

I am using finite element software (COMSOL) to study Photonic Slab, because the Slab is in 3D, it
needs quite a lot of periodic unit to observe desired effect. and periodic boundary condition is not an option because I need to direct a large Gaussian beam into the Photonics Crystal Slab. however I also want to observe the electric field in the farfield, to simulate the large distance in such software would be impossible due to computer constraints, but in principle I think we can deducing the field using just a plane of electric field in the near field. and I believe it is a known technique(huygens extension method?), but I can not found any resource related to this. please help out.